# How can i resolve file to import not found or unreadable in rails 5

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-5, bootstrap-grid

why rails 5, when twitter-boostrap getting below error

file to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets. rails 5

getting error in c9.io while using the boostrp

Comment: you should share your gemfile and error log, only then people will able to trace the source of error. You should read this article on how to ask questions  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you have `gem 'bootstrap'` and `gem 'bootstrap-sass'` both in your gemfile, delete one of them and run **bundle**.

Your **Application.js** should look like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

And **Application.scss** should have:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**Don't forget to Restart the server.**

If it still doesn't work, update your question with error logs, the gemfile and other related code.